# what is "kink"?

Tags: numerical-methods

Pleas tell me that what a "Kink" is and what this sentence means:

> Distance functions have a kink at the interface where $d = 0$ is a local minimum.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.SE! Since it's your first time here, I recommend you read the [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq), which will help you ask better questions and thus get better answers. Another tip: it is generally a good idea to leave non-mathematical content out of your questions, such as requesting a prompt answer. It won't prompt users to answer sooner, and may annoy members of the community.

Comment: I want know what is relationship between gradiant and curvature?

Comment: You have to be more precise about what you mean by "curvature". Are you talking about curvature on a surface? What kind of curvature? Gaussian?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question and be a little more precise about what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10):

A "kink" in a curve would be a point where the curve is continuous, yet the first derivative (gradient) is not continuous. The curvature would be infinite at a kink because the direction changes a finite amount in an infinitesimal distance.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, I believe a "kink" in the function refers to a point at which the function fails to be differentiable. For example, the function $f(x)=|x|$ (which gives the distance between $x$ and $0$) is not differentiable at $x=0$, where the function is $0$ as well.

Comment: thank you,what is relationship between gradiant and curvature from geometry?

Answer (score 5):

As above you can find it via the web as [Cusp (singularity)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_%28singularity%29). See the following graphs:

[image]

[image]