# Why is Transitivity necessary in the definition in the definition of an order on a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

In Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (ed. 3), he provides the following definition (pp. 3)

> **Definition:** Let $S$ be a set. An order on $S$ is a relation, denoted by $<$, with the following two properties:
>
> (1) If $x \in S$ and $y\in S$ then one and only one of the statements: $x<y$, $x=y$, or $y<x$ is true.
>
> (2) If $x,y,z \in S$, if $x<y$ and $y<z$, then $x<z$

The question I asked myself is if property 2 must hold by definition. There answer I had come up with is yes.

Suppose that the above definition is provided with only the first condition. Now take a set, $S=(1,3,5)$. Next define the following order on $S$: $1<3$, $3<5$, $5<1$.

The above order satisfies the first property of the defintion, but not the second. Hence Transitivity as a definition is required.

**Is my reasoning correct, and is there anything I missed?**

Comment: You seem to answer your own question. You ask whether (1) => (2), but you then show that this is not true for the relation you gave for $S$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Now can you also give an example where transitivity holds, but trichotomy fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a fine example how without transitivity, we would not have what we want: an ordered relation.

Can you think of an example of how transitivity alone will not suffice? (Without the first  condition?).

The two properties/conditions are independent: there are relations that are transitive but not trichotomous, and there are relations that are trichotomous, but not transitive. But without having them **both hold** under a given relation, we would not capture, or define, what we want to define: an ***ordered*** relation.

Comment: :I got in this comment from you ideas! Thank you. Can it be coloring?(Sorry if I do not speak English well(╥﹏╥))http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140754/what-is-kink/380936#380936

Comment: $+1^{\infty}...$

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

What you are stating is that the properties are $independent$,
in that you can find examples in which
both are true or one is true and the other false.

A lot of work has been done on independence.

Comment: I was just wondering whether you are aware that you can use [markdown](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for various things, such as *italics* or **bold**; you do not need MathJax for this. I think that `*independent*` *independent* looks better than `$independent$` $independent$ or  `$\text{independent}$` $\text{independent}$

Answer (score 1):

By transitivity you have $1<1$ but also $1=1$, so it is a contradiction to the first condition.