# Is there a good short phrase for a point where a function is continuous but not smooth?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Given a point $x_0$ where a function $f$ is $C^0$ but not $C^1$, how could one call this point intuitively?

I am not looking for a technically precise term (like **a point where $f'$ is discontinuous**), but rather a descriptive and short phrase. I need to write a longer text, where I want to use it to remind the reader of this property, think of sentences like **Condition $Y$ ensures the ??-point $x_0$ of $f$ to fulfil $X$**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word I've most commonly seen used for a point at which a function is continuous but not differentiable is "[kink](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140754/what-is-kink)", as in:

> "The function $f(x) = |x|$ has a kink at the origin."

Comment: A kink is referred to as a 'sharp-point' in certain textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such phrase. Simply reword your sentence: "Condition $Y$ ensure that $f$ is continuous but not smooth at $x_0$, which makes it fulfill $X$". No need for arcane terminology here.

Comment: The phrase is not my problem, just an illustration. I really need a handy word for the point, like it also exists in other contexts, e.g., *the root $x_0$* or *the jump $x_0$* . This is not satisfying, but I think something like *tangent-jump*, but less ugly :)

Comment: Why do you "really need" such a handy word?

Comment: As I said, because always using *the point where $f$ is continuous but not smooth* in longer sentences, where this is merely a side-fact, disctracts from the main statement. It is matter of language. As when you say *the root $x_0$* this is short enough to not distract the reader from the statement *about* the root.

Comment: maybe: $x_0$ is a $continuity-only$ point (''only'' is to mention that there is no more smoothness)